# Can I have a new real time SIP family name other than the well defined family names in asterisk server?

Tags: asterisk, sip, asteriskami, sip-server

In this link http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/index.php?page_id=1735

```
[settings]

<family name> => <driver>,<database name>~np~[~/np~,table_name~np~]~/np~
sippeers => mysql,asterisk,sip_peers
sipusers => mysql,asterisk,sip_users
queues => mysql,asterisk,queue_table
queue_members => mysql,asterisk,queue_member_table
meetme => mysql,asterisk,meetme_table
voicemail => mysql,asterisk^
```

Can't the family name by anything as we wish? Can I have sipfriends as a family name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANY table for example like this

```
sippeers => mysql,asterisk,sipfriends
sipusers => mysql,asterisk,sipfriends
```

Where sipfriends can be table or view(peer update will not work unless you do ONUPDATE trigger).

If you want class enother name, for example something like this

```
sippeers => mysql,asterisk,sipfriends
sipusers => mysql,asterisk,sipfriends
sippeers2 => mysql,asterisk,sipfriends2
sipusers2 => mysql,asterisk,sipfriends2
```

then you need do changes in chan_sip.c to lookup both classes.

Comment: Thanks for answering. is this right
sipfriends => mysql, asterisk, sip_friends
If yes/no, Why?

Comment: Where is yes/no? it is TABLE NAME.

Comment: Nope. That was part of my question. The question is, Is it correct to write

sipfriends => mysql, asterisk, sip_friends

Comment: no, not correct. you have write like i described above

Comment: So that means the realtime family names can be only this

`sippeers
sipusers
iaxpeers
iaxusers
voicemail
musiconhold
queues and queue_members `
and they are like keywords which we cannot change it. Am I right?

Comment: Realtime family name is hardcoded in chan_sip.c. You can use any other name and get info using REALTIME function in dialplan, but chan_sip will get only class that hardcoded.